# docker compose: inside container trying to ping host.docker.internal. but not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ssh-tunnel

I have a docker-compose file and running containers

Inside one of the container i have to access the host ip

I get into the container

```
docker-compose exec webapp /bin/bash
```

and then checking the below command inside the container

```
ping host.docker.internal
```

it says

```
ping: host.docker.internal: Name or service not known
```

How to access host ip inside the container

I have to use host ip because i have to access the ssh tunnel on host

Comment: looks fine to me. `ping host.docker.internal` should usually return an astonishing timing < 2ms. No ports need to be exposed, you have always access to the host. How does the Dockerfile look like?

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer

in the docker-compose file had to add:

```
  webapp:
    image: "python3.10.10_custom_build:latest"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

and inside the container we can access

```
ping host-gateway
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/2897115

[image]